# Replace numbers in string array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a string array like this.

```
var items= ['products/600/application/286/tabbed/301/text',
            'products/600/application/286/tabbed/305/text',
            'products/600/application/500/tabbed/200/text',
            'products/600/application/500/tabbed/300/text',
            'products/600/application/286/tinytext',
            'products/600/differenttext'];
```

I need to replace numbers with consecutive numbers (same numbers should be the same) and output should look like this:

```
 var items= ['products[1]/application[1]/tabbed[1]/text',
                'products[1]/application[1]/tabbed[2]/text',
                'products[1]/application[2]/tabbed[1]/text',
                'products[1]/application[2]/tabbed[2]/text',
                'products[1]/application[1]/tinytext',
                'products[1]/differenttext'];
```

Notice that same numbers should get the same result for example all 286 should be [1] since it is the lowest and the 500 should be replaced with [2] since it's the next bigger one in vertical. Think of them as children. For example for the rows

```
products/600/application/286/tabbed/301/text,
products/600/application/286/tabbed/305/text,
```

its the same till `tabbed`, but after that, there are 2 different children and first one's id is 301 second is 305. So they should [1]and [2]. Now look at the rows

```
products/600/application/286/tabbed/305/text,
products/600/application/500/tabbed/200/text, 
products/600/application/500/tabbed/300/text,
```

In this case application has two children. 286 and 500. And the second one which is 500 has 2 children of it's own. So the children of the 500's should be 1 and 2 (200 and 300)

After I apply `temp= items[0].match(/\d+/g);` I get the result `[600,286,301]`. Should I use a json object to put all the result I get from `temp` or use 2d arrays maybe?

Comment: JSON is irrelevant here - it's a serialisation format

Comment: It's unclear to me what the question is

Comment: @Ege it would help if your example output was actually correct...

Comment: @Alnitak actually my result is exactly what I expect. Maybe I couldn't express what I want clearly

Comment: you've completely changed the semantics of the question.   I can't figure out how each of the numbers is supposed to be derived.

Comment: Look at the numbers vertically. For example first one is after products. The value is not important. In this case it's 600 so it should be [1].  Now look at the second column, there's 286 and 500 so they should be [1] and [2] in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this using **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** and **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)**

```js
var items = ['products/600/application/286/tabbed/301/text',
  'products/600/application/286/tabbed/305/text',
  'products/600/application/500/tabbed/200/text',
  'products/600/application/500/tabbed/300/text',
  'products/600/application/286/tinytext',
  'products/600/differenttext'
];
var num = {};

var res = items.map(function(v, i) { // iterate over the array for generating updated array
  return v.replace(/\/(\d+)\/(?:(.*?)\/(\d+)\/(?:(.*?)\/(\d+)\/)?)?/, function(m, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5) { //find the number to replace
    var str = replace(m1, 'main', 0);
    if (m3) {
      str += m2 + replace(m3, m1);
      if (m5)
        str += m4 + replace(m5, m1 + '_' + m3);
    }
    return str;
  });
});

function replace(mat, ind1) {
  if (!num[ind1])
    num[ind1] = {
      ind: 0
    };
  if (num[ind1][mat]) // check index already defined
    return '/[' + num[ind1][mat] + ']/'; // if defined use the previous
  num[ind1][mat] = ++num[ind1].ind ;// else update index in object
  return '/[' + num[ind1].ind + ']/'; // and return the replace string
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

---

**UPDATE :**
If number of occurrence is more than 3 then you can do something like this,

```js
var items = ['products/600/application/286/tabbed/301/text/222/kjkjk',
  'products/600/application/286/tabbed/301/text/112/kjkjk',
  'products/600/application/286/tabbed/305/text/222/kjkjk',
  'products/600/application/500/tabbed/200//text/222/kjkjk',
  'products/600/application/500/tabbed/300/text',
  'products/600/application/286/tinytext',
  'products/600/differenttext'
];
var num = {};

var res = items.map(function(v, i) { // iterate over the array for generating updated array
  var match = 'match';
  return v.replace(/\/(\d+)\//g, function(m, m1) {
    var res = replace(match, m1);
    match += '_' + m1;
    return res;
  });
});
78

function replace(ind1, m1) {
  if (!num[ind1])
    num[ind1] = {
      ind: 0
    };
  if (!num[ind1][m1])
    num[ind1][m1] = ++num[ind1].ind;
  return '/[' + num[ind1][m1] + ']/';
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: good answer, although I would've been tempted to use a map to hold the number->index table (and a separate index for the table size) instead of an array with an amortized O(n) lookup cost.

Comment: Thank you it's a good answer but your's give the result ["products/[1]/application/[2]/tabbed/[3]/text", "products/[1]/application/[2]/tabbed/[4]/text", "products/[1]/application/[5]/tabbed/[6]/text", "products/[1]/application/[5]/tabbed/[7]/text", "products/[1]/application/[2]/tinytext", "products/[1]/differenttext"] .  So you get for example [5] after application where I need [1] and [2] after application since there are 2 different numbers to replace

Comment: Now it gives "products/[1]/application/[1]/tabbed/[1]/text",
   "products/[1]/application/[1]/tabbed/[2]/text",
   "products/[1]/application/[2]/tabbed/[3]/text",
   "products/[1]/application/[2]/tabbed/[4]/text",
   "products/[1]/application/[1]/tinytext",
   "products/[1]/differenttext" which is more close but still 3 and 4 should be 1

Comment: Thanks this was what i need.

Comment: @Ege : glad to help :)